virt-manager Error connecting to graphical console
I've had this problem now for several months and haven't been able to find a suitable solution.  When searching I find a lot of very old posts about the problem but none seem to related.  Mostly talk about a bug in older versions.  It used to work fine but at some point it broke, maybe after an update but can't say for certain.
Whenever I try to Open, "show the graphical console," a KVM in virt-manager I get the following error: Error connecting to graphical console: could not get a reference to type class
What I've tried:

Tried creating a new test KVM and had the same error message when trying to Open.
Purge and reinstall virt-manager
make sure that I'm in the libvirt group
Run virt-manager from the terminal with sudo

I'm a novice Linux user at best and I don't know where to turn.  And help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.
Update 1
After a lot of searching, purging and reinstalling I believe that I have narrowed the problem down to virt-viewer.  Whenever running virt-viewer from the command line I get the following error: virt-viewer: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbredirhost.so.1: undefined symbol: libusb_transfer_set_stream_id  I get this error regardless of the virt-viewer command, ie virt-viewer -h , version ect.
I have a strong suspicion that the root cause was when I was trying to get some old software working for my LogiTech mouse and keyboard working.  Installing an older lib or something possibly?

I'm still having this issue.  I did find this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/868290/virt-viewer-not-starting-up-correctly.  I tried running virt-viewer from the command line and I got this error message:
:~$ virt-viewer --version
virt-viewer: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbredirhost.so.1: undefined symbol: libusb_transfer_set_stream_id
~$ virt-viewer --help
virt-viewer: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbredirhost.so.1: undefined symbol: libusb_transfer_set_stream_id
Maybe there's something here that may point someone to the problem?

Fixed it with a lot help for a friend.  Turned out to a file conflict with libusb-1.  Removing the symlink and reinstalling virt-manger, virt-viewer solved the all the issues.

Very similar case: nuitrack installed another libusb version in a directory with higher priority.
To get the error I was running virt-manager --no-fork
Then I did locate on the library that linked to libusb with a grep usb, found that the nuitrack installed another libusb. Removed that software and confirmed that ldd now points to the right one, and now it works.
Do not have the exact commands anymore.
